# ggplot Grouped barplot with R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am having difficulties creating a grouped barplot. This is my first time using anything other than the scatter plot in R. There is the Team, and the points they give up to the position(Below the Code). C, D, and W. Going off the r-graph-gallery for the code below.

```
library(ggplot2)
positions=rep(c("C","W","D"))

ggplot(data=stats, aes(fill=positions, y=0,200,x=PtsAgRdTm))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "indentity")
```

Below is the `df` as `stats` than converted to `data`.

```
PtsAgRdTm     C       D       W 
ANH         57.73   65.08   56.08
ARI         33      29.24   26.99
BOS         56.64   44.97   56.15
BUF         35.36   31.04   38.35
CAR         42.6    49.79   78.03
CLS         38.23   53.16   67.92
CGY         56.19   54.87   78.54
CHI         37.04   47.93   74.95
COL         54.87   47.83   78.22
DAL         59.05   39.67   33.3
DET         26.11   34.15   71.21
EDM         57.64   53.01   43.14
FLA         71.09   44.85   44.91
LA          53.06   48.62   42.11
MIN         41.86   51.44   51.93
MON         36.6    50      89.02
NJ          26.95   34.64   49.61
NSH         43.12   60.05   83.11
NYI         51.58   46.36   46.99
NYR         75.15   104.19  177.69
OTT         51.01   64.75   75.05
PHI         65.96   54.69   40.56
PIT         42.67   38.08   52.33
SJ          70.83   56.66   44.31
STL         40.51   58.83   81.85
TB          68      50.93   58.22
TOR         71.28   42.17   21.5
VAN         29.81   28.79   41.4
VGK         40.09   43.63   63.49
WPG         49.66   48.09   77.08
WAS         47.68   52.02   70.12
```

Comment: Please use `dput(stats)` to show your data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  gather(key, value, -PtsAgRdTm) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=PtsAgRdTm, y=value, fill=key)) +
   geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

You transform the data from wide to long using tidyr's gather function, then plot the bars in a "dodge" or a "stack" way.

Comment: When I run that I get `> d %>%
+   gather(key, value, -PtsAgRdTm) %>%
+   ggplot(aes(x=PtsAgRdTm, y=value, fill=key)) +
+   geom_col(position = "dodge")
Error in eval(lhs, parent, parent) : object 'd' not found`

Comment: `d` stores your data.frame. You have to change this to the name you specified. Something like this `my_dataframe %>%`

Comment: I tried that using data instead of stats. Thank you Jimbou!